# Modules use each other in cycle. Compilation error in Perl

Tags: perl, exporter

There are 3 modules, so that they use each other by pattern
a -> b -> c -> a. I cannot compile such case.

For instance,

I get a compilation error

```
"Throw" is not exported by the LIB::Common::Utils module
Can't continue after import errors at /root/bin/ppm/LIB/Common/EnvConfigMgr.pm line 13
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/bin/ppm/LIB/Common/EnvConfigMgr.pm line 13.
```

Utils.pm

```
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
        GetDirCheckSum
        AreDirsEqual
        onError
        Throw);
use LIB::Common::Logger::Log;
```

Log.pm

```
use Log::Log4perl;

use LIB::Common::EnvConfigMgr qw/Expand/;
```

EnvConfigMgr.pm

```
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT = qw(TransformShellVars ExpandString InitSearchLocations);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(Expand);

use LIB::Common::Utils qw/Throw/;
```

Why doesn't it get compiled and how to make it work?

Comment: You should also include stubs for the functions you're exporting so we can copy/paste it and try.

Comment: We need to see more than this as **simbabque** says. Please show a `main.pl` that uses these modules and displays the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `require` instead of `use` somewhere in the loop of dependencies so as to delay the binding. It is most convenient with a module that exports nothing, as otherwise you need to write an explicit `import` call

In your case `LIB::Common::Logger::Log` doesn't use `Export`, so putting

```
require LIB::Common::Logger::Log
```

into `LIB/Common/Utils.pm` fixes the problem

*You have access to the code that isn't working, and you could have saved us a lot of time by simply showing the malfunctioning code. You ignored two comments asking for more information so I have set up these files*

Note that this code does nothing: it simply compiles

#### LIB/Common/Utils.pm

```
package LIB::Common::Utils;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = qw/
    GetDirCheckSum
    AreDirsEqual
    onError
    Throw
/;

require LIB::Common::Logger::Log;

sub GetDirCheckSum { }

sub AreDirsEqual { }

sub onError { }

sub Throw { }

1;
```

#### LIB/Common/Logger/EnvConfigMgr.pm

```
package LIB::Common::EnvConfigMgr;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT = qw/ TransformShellVars ExpandString InitSearchLocations /;
our @EXPORT_OK = 'Expand';

use LIB::Common::Utils 'Throw';

sub TransformShellVars { }

sub ExpandString { }

sub InitSearchLocations { }

sub Expand { }

1;
```

#### LIB/Common/Logger/Log.pm

```
package LIB::Common::Logger::Log;

use Log::Log4perl;

use LIB::Common::EnvConfigMgr 'Expand';

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;

use LIB::Common::Utils;
```

Comment: Can you type in details of phrase "...to delay the binding..."?

Comment: @osiv: The term *late binding* is a bit of a misnomer here. It properly refers to the *object-oriented* concept whereby a method call is resolved *at run time* according to the principle of inheritance, and not at compile time. It is the method that Perl uses. What I meant here was the more general idea of establishing the meaning of any identifier at run time.

Comment: @osiv: `use` employs an implicit `BEGIN` block, so the module is compiled, and any symbols are imported, during the compilation phase. `require` is executed at run time, so you can break the loop of dependencies by using at least one `require`, when the loop becomes a *chain* with a beginning and an end. You will often see `require` in a CPAN module for this exact reason.